How can I change a TextInput's selection and fire its onSelectionChange event in unit testing?
I have a React Native component with a TextInput that I'm testing. Part of the behaviour of this component relies on handling the current selection position via onSelectionChange — that is, it matters where the text cursor is in the text field as we type.
That component looks basically like this:
type Selection = { start: number, end?: number };

const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<Selection>({ start: 0, end: 0 });

  // do some things with value and selection, e.g.:
  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug(value.slice(selection.start, selection.end));
  }, [value, selection.start, selection.end]);

  const onSelectionChange = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputSelectionChangeEventData>) => {
    setSelection(event.nativeEvent.selection);
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      testID="input"
      value={text}
      onChangeText={setMessageText}
      selection={selection}
      onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
    />
  );
}

In our unit tests for this component I can change the value just fine to test the behaviour associated with the value (via React Native Testing Library's fireEvent.changeText):
const input = screen.getByTestId("input");
fireEvent.changeText(input, "some text");

However changing the text doesn't move the text cursor, so the selection always remains as { start: 0 }. To properly test the behaviour of this component, I need to be able to set the selection to other positions. This means I need my code to somehow call setSelection({ start: 3, end: 3 }) and so on after value changes.
How can I get the onSelectionChange event to fire in my unit tests?
I think this issue is essentially one of two things:

How can I fire a selection change event such that it will surface from onSelectionChange?
Alternately, how do I access the function that was bound to the TextInput's onSelectionChange property so as to call it directly?

Should I just be setting up a jest mock for <TextInput /> with something that automatically updates the selection when the text changes?

I've found I can actually straightforwardly access the onSelectionChange binding via the object's props:
const input = screen.getByTestId("input");
const onSelectionChange = input.props["onSelectionChange"];

This means I can build selection change events and invoke them during tests:
import { act, fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react-native";

let onSelectionChange: (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputSelectionChangeEventData>) => void;

/**
 * Mock a Text Input Selection event that just contains a selection.
 */
function makeSelectionEvent(selection: { start: number, end: number }) {
  return {
    nativeEvent: {
      selection,
    },
  } as any as NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputSelectionChangeEventData>;
}

beforeEach(() => {
  render(<Component />);

  const input = screen.getByTestId("input");
  onSelectionChange = input.props["onSelectionChange"];
});

test(`change the value and selection`, () => {
  const input = screen.getByTestId("input");

  fireEvent.changeText(input, "text");
  act(() => {
    onSelectionChange(makeSelectionEvent({ start: 4, end: 4 });
  });

  // Our component will now have both its value and selection updated.
  expect(...)
});

